# How to move the image in a div a little to the bottom

Tags: html, css

Okay so I'm a very beginner on `CSS` and I don't know if the title of this question goes as what I want to know. I've this on the website that I'm making:
[image]
 This square box contains the featured image of a product. Now the image is a rectangle and I want to show it in a square. It's okay if the dress cuts off but the face of the girl needs to be shown.
So my question is there any way I can move this image center point to top-left? Please feel free to ask me if I've not made the point clear of you need additional information.
 This is the name of the div this image is placed in:

```
.attachment-post-thumbnail
{
 /*what to write here*/   
}
```

Based on the comments here is the code of this section:[image][image]

Comment: Post the code that recreates the screenshot and problem you're having now.

Comment: Is your image being set as the background of the div, or is it a separate image element inside the div?

Comment: @Kurt it's not the background image that I'm sure of

Comment: Seeing you full code for this section would still be helpful since the exact answer might change depending on what you all have, but you could try putting `display: relative;` on the parent and then use absolute positioning on the image and then use `top: [some value];`. Or just through `display: relative;` on the image element and then use `top: [some value];`

Comment: @Kurt I am sorry but I'm new to editing stuff from CSS. I've added two photos of the code which Google Chrome gave me on Inspect. Hope it clears the question.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the image is defined as a background-image for its container `.attachment-post-thumbnail`.

Most likely the background-image's size is set to `cover` at the moment, and the position to "center center"  (i.e. horizontally and vertically).

So you can still use `background-size: cover`, but add `background-position: center top;`  to your `.attachment-post-thumbnail` rule, which should align the top of the image to the top of its container. If that doesn't work, you can try to add `!important` (i.e. `.attachment-post-thumbnail { background-position: center top !important; }`)  to enforce it.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for but as this is wordpress and I'm overwriting the .attachment-post-thumbnail in custom css section. So wordpress actually converts the images 300x300. Maybe the problem is ther. Anyhow thank you for your help.

Comment: It certainly doesn't convert the images to 300x300, since that would compress/distort them (showing the whole image, but distorted). It just positions them the way I described.

Comment: Ooo... well then your answer didn't work :/ I've added `.attachment-post-thumbnail { 
    background-position: center top;
}` and if I add !important it shows a warning that `Use of !Important` but I still saved it but it is not working. I've attached some more code in screenshots may be that can help better understand the problem.